Can I require a method to only accept a parameter type that is assignable from a certain concrete type?
I have a concrete type ("B") which is a subtype of several other types ("A1", "A2" in the example below), and I want to create a method that possibly returns the supertype, or B. So essentially I want to require that B is a subtype of my generic parameter. A code example might make it clearer:
class Scratch {
  interface A1 {
    default void print1() { System.out.println("A1"); }
  }

  interface A2 {
    default void print2() { System.out.println("A2"); }
  }

  interface A3 {
    default void print3() { System.out.println("A3"); }
  }

  static class A1Impl implements A1 {}

  static class A2Impl implements A2 {}

  static class A3Impl implements A3 {}

  static class B implements A1, A2 {}

  // Is there any way to make this fail at compile-time if B is not a subtype of T?
  static <T> Optional<T> get(Supplier<T> provider, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (someCondition()) {
      return Optional.of(provider.get());
    } else {
      // I want to avoid an unchecked cast here to get compile-time safety
      return Optional.of((T) new B());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Should succeed because B is a subtype of A1 and A2
    get(A1Impl::new, A1.class).ifPresent(A1::print1);
    get(A2Impl::new, A2.class).ifPresent(A2::print2);
    // Will fail at run-time because B is not a subtype of A3
    // Is there any way to make this fail at compile-time?
    get(A3Impl::new, A3.class).ifPresent(A3::print3);
  }
}

I want to forbid the call get(A3Impl::new, A3.class) on compile-time because else the return Optional.of((T) new B()); inside my get method would throw an exception on runtime.
Ideally, one would like something like
static <T super B> Optional<T> get(Supplier<T> provider, Class<T> clazz)

but I am aware that is not possible in Java. Is there any way to achieve compile-time safety here?

Why do you want that? How would you use it? If you just want a supertype of B, Object fulfils that. And since any class implementing A3 is ultimately a subclass of Object, what is it that you want to forbid?

Object is indeed a valid type for T, but if I have a more specific type of T I want the method to return that type so that I can continue to operate on it without doing an unsafe cast from Object to my more specific type. And I also want to prevent the method from being called and causing a runtime exception because T was not assignable from B.

Well, depending on the caller, the more specific type can be A1 or A2. So I want the returned type to be resolved based on the method parameters (specifically the type parameter T, which could be A1 or A2 in the above example). So, to be specific about what I want to forbid, I want to forbid the method to be called with a type parameter that makes the cast (T)new B() fail.

I am starting to get some of it, thanks. You can improve the cast inside the method to return Optional.of(clazz.cast(new B()));; but it still will not catch the call using A3 on compile-time. You may also check if (! clazz.isAssignableFrom(B.class)) for validation. I can’t see how a compile-time check would be possible, sorry.

It’s not ideal. You could pass B::new as argument if you could accept doing so: get(A1Impl::new, B::new). Declare static <T> Optional<T> get(Supplier<? extends T> provider, Supplier<? extends T> creator). get(A1Impl::new, B::new).ifPresent(A1::print1); still works. You will also be allowed get(A3Impl::new, B::new), but it returns an Optional<Object>, so .ifPresent(A3::print3) will be caught on compile time.

If you want to ensure the return type has a B, can you use <T extends B> Optional<B> get(Supplier<T> provider)? Would that work for you? The rest of the code works with that, and you don't even need clazz.

@DavidConrad I don’t think the OP necessarily wants a B. Just to ensure that in the else case a B can be returned. With your method signature get(A1Impl::new) does not compile, which it should. I modified it from under the “Should succeed” section of the OP’s code.

I am afraid that the following question, if just remotely related, then perhaps still close enough that it doesn’t give much hope for what you were trying to obtain: Can a Java method return different types based on conditions in the method?
